# A compendium of Shas Concepts?

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara

Is there a sefer, a website, or an app with all the concepts in Shas? 
Halachic Concepts such as - "Women are exempt from time-bound commandments".

Comment: There is a sefer called Klalei hagemara 3 vol,but it's in Hebrew

Comment: Is http://www.webshas.org/ useful?

Comment: Gr8!!! @Rosends

Comment: Let me know what the Hebrew sefer is called. I can translate Hebrew lol. And, It's not my question @mbloch

Comment: @Moshe you are right, the other is not your question. Regarding this one, I am still confused. Are you looking for a "readable book" which you can read from beginning to end to understand key talmudic concepts? Or a dictionary/encyclopedia reference-style book which you consult for specific questions?

Comment: Either one @mbloch

Answer (score 8):

The multi-volume אנציקלופדיה תלמודית has many such, but is as yet incomplete. It's in Hebrew. I think I've heard that some volumes have been translated (or perhaps issued separately) in English.

Comment: We have See Chemed older than the encyclopedia

Comment: @kouty, good point! Please post an answer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the sefer. I work with kesef nivhar. The best answer is encyclopedia as you wrote

Answer (score 5):

Aspaklaria is very good and it's free.

http://www.aspaklaria.info

Comment: Aspaklaria is an encyclopedia of aggadah, not halachah

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [*HaMafteach*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9653013262), I think it fits the description you mentioned. It is in English.

From description of book:

> HaMafteach locates for you every topic, saying, anecdote, maxim, parable, significant subject matter, law, Biblical exegesis, and Biblical and Talmudic personality mentioned in the Talmud. The English edition includes a transliteration of Hebrew and Aramaic words and phrases, and a new integrated glossary. Hamafteach is an invaluable sefer for Rebbeim, teachers, authors of seforim, researchers and scholars, as well as for anyone who wishes to swim in the yam shel Talmud.

Comment: Not sure this addresses his q,the Mafteach is basiscally a giant index of the gemara, it itself does not explain concepts

Comment: There's a free HaMafteach app in the play store. But there isn't a section specifically for halachik entries, (or any other groups of concepts) so I don't think that's what the OP is looking for. But I may be wrong.

Comment: surely this includes 'all the concepts in Shas', no? @sam

Comment: halachic concepts was only a exampled qualifier

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a "readable book" which you can read from beginning to end to understand key talmudic concepts (rather than a dictionary or encyclopedia), then R Adin Steinsaltz' [Reference Guide to the Talmud](https://www.korenpub.com/koren_en_usd/koren/talmud/talmud-reference-books/reference-guide-to-the-talmud.html)

> clearly and concisely explains the Talmud’s fundamental structure,
>   concepts, terminology, assumptions, and inner logic; provides
>   essential historical and biographical information; and includes
>   appendixes, a key to abbreviations, and a comprehensive index.

Practically it describes talmudic methodology, terminology, hermeneutical principles and halakhic concepts (there are more than 100 pages of these in my edition). It covers "Women are exempt from time-bound commandments" both under "*mitzvot*" and "women" and they are cross-references in the index.

Answer (score 1):

Kesef Nivchar brings the gemara and primary Rishonim arranged by concept, covering 160 concepts:

http://hebrewbooks.org/19582
(There are newer prints available.)